# Taking average of list of list ignoring zero values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, mean

I would like to take mean for each column by ignoring zero values in each column.
The array is :

```
array([[ 12.,  26.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 12.,  27.,  36.,  46.,  56.,  66.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 13.,  22.,  38.,  50.,  66.,  81.,  94., 107.],
       [  3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

The result would be:

```
[10,25,37,48,61,73.5,94,107]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What, specifically, is going wrong with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You have a NumPy array here, so use NumPy. One way is to convert `0` values to `NaN` and then use [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
A = np.array([[ 12.,  26.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [ 12.,  27.,  36.,  46.,  56.,  66.,   0.,   0.],
              [ 13.,  22.,  38.,  50.,  66.,  81.,  94., 107.],
              [  3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])

B = A.copy()
B[B == 0] = np.nan
res = np.nanmean(B, axis=0)

print(res)

array([  10. ,   25. ,   37. ,   48. ,   61. ,   73.5,   94. ,  107. ])
```

Or use masked arrays via [`np.ma.masked_where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html#numpy-ma-masked-where):

```
import numpy.ma as ma

res = np.nanmean(ma.masked_where(A == 0, A), axis=0).data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.true_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) to divide the sum of the array, by the number of non-zero elements, which is fairly performant:

```
np.true_divide(A.sum(0), (A != 0).sum(0))
```

```
array([ 10. ,  25. ,  37. ,  48. ,  61. ,  73.5,  94. , 107. ])
```

---

***Performance***

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10000, 10000)).astype(float)

In [71]: %timeit np_nanmean(A)
1.73 s ± 3.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [72]: %timeit np_masked_nanmean(A)
1.93 s ± 7.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [73]: %timeit np_true_divide(A)
319 ms ± 5.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = [[ 12.,  26.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [ 12.,  27.,  36.,  46.,  56.,  66.,   0.,   0.],
   [ 13.,  22.,  38.,  50.,  66.,  81.,  94., 107.],
   [  3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]
result_lst = map(lambda x:sum(x)/len(x),[tup if 0.0 not in tup else filter(lambda x: x != 0.0,tup) for tup in map(list,zip(*lst))])
print result_lst
```

> ```
> Result : [10.0, 25.0, 37.0, 48.0, 61.0, 73.5, 94.0, 107.0]
> ```

Hi,I know we can get output in many ways,But i dont want to use any                 Modules(numpy),i just want to use list Compressions to get Our result.
Let Me explain how i do this:

1. `map(list,zip(*lst))` will give list of lists to compare index based
2. `filter` function will give list with no zeroes
3. finally we finding average

Guide me if i can make any efficient change in my list compression